# Is there any difference between "miss out" and "lose out"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *miss out* and *lose out*?

> If you don't take the course, you will **miss out** a lot.
>
> If you don't take the course, you will **lose out** a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. miss out is simply loosing an opportunity while lose out is not getting an opportunity  that others are getting.
For example "we will repeat the lesson so you don't miss out.  " while "if we do not win the elections,  we will lose out to the Republican party" .
So we lose out  something to someone or other bodies .
And we miss out something simply.